# Doxygen: Add new type or structure

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I want to use doxygen to document a c-like language. 
I got some issues to solve keywords which are unknown in the context.

One example, I have to use a callback function called

```
on timer
{
  //normal c- code
}
```

My question is now, can I adopt doxygen to accept the new keyword? 
I would like to add this keyword like a function or variable acc. to

```
/** This timer is used for something. */   
on timer
{
}
```

or maybe

```
/** \ontimer This timer is used for something. */   
on timer
{
}
```

The documentation of doxygen describes something with ALIASES or \xrefitem but as I understand I can only generate new sections for known types or am I wrong?
Actually I am surrounding the unknown code with a condition block out to avoid errors in the generated output.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand is "on" a keyword which doxygen cannot interpret. One solution could be to declare the keyword `on` as a predfined macro in the doxyile by using the the `PREDEFINED` tag as follows:

```
PREDEFINED             = on=
```

Yes, the `=` at the end is not a typo! This tells the preprocessor of doxygen to substitute the keyword `on` with a empty string. Note that you have to set `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` to `YES`.

If the `on` keyword only appears before callback functions you could alternatively set the `PREDEFINED` macro to `void`:

```
PREDEFINED             = on=void
```